# Error messages once a NativeScript app loads on Android

Tags: nativescript, angular-nativescript

after updating my app to NativeScript 5.1/tns-core-modules to 5.1.2, I am having this messages once the app starts:

```
01-30 09:59:57.001 12223 12223 I art     :   at java.lang.Object com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodNative(int, int, java.lang.String, int, boolean, java.lang.Object[]) (Runtime.java:-2)
01-30 09:59:57.001 12223 12223 I art     :   at java.lang.Object com.tns.Runtime.dispatchCallJSMethodNative(int, java.lang.String, boolean, long, java.lang.Class, java.lang.Object[]) (Runtime.java:1120)
01-30 09:59:57.002 12223 12223 I art     :   at java.lang.Object com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodImpl(java.lang.Object, java.lang.String, java.lang.Class, boolean, long, java.lang.Object[]) (Runtime.java:1000)
01-30 09:59:57.002 12223 12223 I art     :   at java.lang.Object com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(java.lang.Object, java.lang.String, java.lang.Class, boolean, long, java.lang.Object[]) (Runtime.java:987)
01-30 09:59:57.002 12223 12223 I art     :   at java.lang.Object com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(java.lang.Object, java.lang.String, java.lang.Class, boolean, java.lang.Object[]) (Runtime.java:967)
01-30 09:59:57.002 12223 12223 I art     :   at java.lang.Object com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(java.lang.Object, java.lang.String, java.lang.Class, java.lang.Object[]) (Runtime.java:959)
01-30 09:59:57.002 12223 12223 I art     :   at java.lang.Object com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodNative(int, int, java.lang.String, int, boolean, java.lang.Object[]) (Runtime.java:-2)
01-30 09:59:57.002 12223 12223 I art     :   at java.lang.Object com.tns.Runtime.dispatchCallJSMethodNative(int, java.lang.String, boolean, long, java.lang.Class, java.lang.Object[]) (Runtime.java:1120)
01-30 09:59:57.002 12223 12223 I art     :   at java.lang.Object com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodImpl(java.lang.Object, java.lang.String, java.lang.Class, boolean, long, java.lang.Object[]) (Runtime.java:1000)
01-30 09:59:57.002 12223 12223 I art     :   at java.lang.Object com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(java.lang.Object, java.lang.String, java.lang.Class, boolean, long, java.lang.Object[]) (Runtime.java:987)
01-30 09:59:57.002 12223 12223 I art     :   at java.lang.Object com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(java.lang.Object, java.lang.String, java.lang.Class, boolean, java.lang.Object[]) (Runtime.java:967)
01-30 09:59:57.002 12223 12223 I art     :   at java.lang.Object com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(java.lang.Object, java.lang.String, java.lang.Class, java.lang.Object[]) (Runtime.java:959)
```

I have removed the /core_modules, /hooks, /platforms/android folders and the messages are still showing.

Any clue whats going on?

Thanks!

Comment: Please be sure to include the actual exception line (it's the line immediately preceding the first `:  at` line). Without it, it's like you've given us the punchline without telling the joke.

Comment: @IanMacDonald thats the full error, i get it too. you can safely ignore it, it looks to be part of ns that doesnt compile correctly or something. its never caused me issues and ive had that error appear now for probably 2+ months, i think it started occuring in ns5, but it may have been earlier

Comment: That is all I get here... the messages are shown as soon as the app installed and launched for the first time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are only warnings and you don't have to worry about it. Still, if you are interested in what is causing them and how to (possibly) remove them, see the discussion in the opened issue here:

https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-cli/issues/4300#issuecomment-439092313